# How to use pre and post check in Perl?

Tags: perl

We have a `*.Tex` file contains lot of tables and have a keyword inside the table and which we have to fetch the tables having keyword.

For Keyword Eg: `\\tobesplit`

Input File:

```
\begin{table1} ....\body1 .... \tbody1 .... \end{table1}
some text ... 
\begin{table2} .... \body2 .... \\tobesplit ... \tbody2... \end{table2}
some text ...
\begin{table3} ....\body3... \tbody3... \end{table3}
some text ...
```

Code:

```
my ($tpre,$tmatchs,$tposts) = "";
while($incnt=~m/\\tobesplit/gs)
{
    $tpre = $tpre.$`; $tmatchs = $&; $tposts = $';
    print "hi...\n";
    my ($headers,$footers) = "";
```

> Here we need to get the pre-content of table 2 from starting

```
    if($tpre=~m/(?<!.*\\begin\{table)\\body\d+/g) {  $headers = $&; }
```

> Here we need to get the post-content of table 2 to ending

```
    if($tposts=~m/\\tbody(.*?)\\end\{table\d+\}/i) {  $footers = $&; }
    print "-$headers-\n";
    print "-$footers-\n";
}
```

> Note: table123 with numbers for identification purpose only...

I don't how to use pre and post using lookbehind and lookafter functions in perl. Could you please someone help me on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend that you use a LaTeX parser. See for example [LaTeX::TOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::TOM). Another option is to use [Perl 6 grammars](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammar_tutorial).

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I need to install perl 6?

Comment: @ssr1012 no, as he said, you can use Latex::TOM see his comment for a link to the module, with examples.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: Ok great. We will check.

Comment: @ssr1012 Cool, I hope you manage! PS! I hope by _"we"_ you are not referring to multiple personalities :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: Ok I will check...

Answer (score 1):

[Pegex](https://metacpan.org/release/Pegex) is very useful if you are considering using a grammars. It gives Perl5 a good chunk of the basic Perl6 style grammar parsing. Pegex is an excellent and under-used module.